# Muting audio when receiving a VOIP call - which software is compatible?

Tags: windows-7, audio, voip

Windows is able to reduce/mute other audio when it detects communications activity.
What VOIP softphone is compatible with this?

I will have a USB headset and will listen to music and would like it to automatically mute/unmute whenever a call comes in.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: @techie007 This is to do with a generally unknown Windows feature. It's so unknown that most VOIP applications don't work with it. Therefore I think this is a great question for SuperUser.

Comment: The only way this question can be legitimately answered is by referring you a list of products that work with this Windows feature, which I would regard a product recommendation request. You may want to broaden it a bit by not specifically asking for software titles.

Comment: @Moses Where can I ask the question for specific software products? I can't find any that are compatible with this often unknown Windows feature.

Comment: Why would you need to use softphone that uses **that** specific feature of Windows? Most softphones lower the volume of other sounds (i know phonerlite does it) and if this feature is not present in older Windows-versions it wouldn't work. So your question would be better if you asked for a softphone which lowers other sound when in a call. (Although that would still be asking for software recommendations ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Rik, [PhonerLite](http://phonerlite.de/) is compatible with this setting in Windows. When receiving a VOIP call, it will lower the volume or mute other applications depending on the setting in Windows. I hope this helps someone else.